# Typescript: Pattern for building an object one property at a time

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, types

This situation is especially common when creating a complicated object to insert into a DB. I may have an object that requires 20 fields, each coming from elsewhere.

```
interface Cat {hair: HairType, name: string, ...20 other properties}
function insertCatIntoDB(cat: Cat){...}

function createCatForUser(userType: UserType){
  const newCat: Partial<Cat> = {};
  newCat.name = getNewCatNameForUserType(userType);
  ...business logic involving the setting of the other properties
  insertCatIntoDB(newCat); // Problem: newCat is Partial<Cat> 
                           // instead of Cat despite having assigned all of the properties

}
```

I see a few ways to deal with this.

1. refactor the "getting" of each property into a new function and then calling something like

```
insertCatIntoDB({hair: getHairByUserType, name: getNameByUserType, ...})
```

but then if the business logic required to create the properties is relatively simple you're creating 20 functions, each maybe 3 lines of code, that will only be called once which isn't great for readability.

2. Similar, but instead of creating new functions you just do it "inside" the options, e.g.

`insertCatIntoDB({name: userType === UserType.girl ? 'cookie' : (userType === userType.boy ? 'tiger' : 'persian'), ...})` but even in this example with very simple logic this quickly becomes unwieldy and hard to read.

3. Doing something like `insertCatIntoDB(newCat as Cat)`

but this isn't type checked.

I'm looking for suggestions on better ways to deal with these situations.

Answer (score 1):

When I look at the numbers of the properties in your interface and according to your refactoring ideas, I have several thoughts regarding this:

- Split this interface into smaller interfaces according to `Interface segregation principles`. We can use the `Information experts principle` and `High cohesion principle` to create several Interfaces which hold the information of several high cohesion attributes. In this way, instead of creating 20 functions to get attribute by type, you only need several instances.
- Use Factory pattern to create the getNameByUserType, getHairByUserType, getOtherAttributesByType etc ...
- Use the Builder pattern to initialize the cat object and inject the above factory to the builder (reference: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/builder). For example:

```
    const cat = new CatBuilder()
     .byUserType(userType)
     .withGetByUserTypeFactory(GetByUserTypeFactory)
     .withHair()
     .withName()
     .(...other attributes...)
     .build();
```